# Checkbox converted into button and button has image. How to change color only of transparent part of image on check and hover?

Tags: html, css

Here are html and css. Checkboxes from html is converted in buttons with css.
And button has png image. I want to change color only for transparent part of image when that button is checked or hover. What is the best way to do this?

This is html:

```
    <div class="container">
      <div class="cat first">
         <label>
            <input type="checkbox" value="First"><span>&nbsp;</span>
         </label>
      </div>


      <div class="cat second">
         <label>
            <input type="checkbox" value="Second"><span>&nbsp;</span>
         </label>
      </div>

      <div class="cat third">
         <label>
            <input type="checkbox" value="Third"><span>&nbsp;</span>
         </label>
      </div>

      <div class="cat fourth">
         <label>
            <input type="checkbox" value="Fourth"><span>&nbsp;</span>
         </label>
      </div>

    </div><!-- end container -->
```

This is css. It also change color of button on check but change whole button not only transparent part of image:

```
    body {
      font-family: sans-serif;
      font-size: 14px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      text-align: center;
      background-color: #535353;
    }

    .container{
      margin: 20px 10px 10px 37px;
    }

    /* div label input {margin-right: 100px;} */

    .cat{
      display: inline-block;
      margin: 4px;
      background-color: #535353;
      border-radius: 14px;
      border: 1px solid #adadad;
      overflow: hidden;
      float: left;
    }

    .cat label {
      float: left; line-height: 4.0em;
      width: 4.0em; height: 4.0em;

    }

    .cat label span {
      text-align: center;
      padding: 3px 0;
      display: block;
    }

    .cat label input {
      position: absolute;
      display: none;
      color: #fff !important;

    }
    /* selects all of the text within the input element and changes the color of the text */
    .cat label input + span{color: #fff;}


    /* This will declare how a selected input will look giving generic properties */
    .cat input:checked + span {
        color: #ffffff;
        text-shadow: 0 0  6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    }


    .cat.first {
      position: relative;
      background: url('Image.png') no-repeat center center;
      background-size: cover;

      background-size: 70%;
      /* height:50px;
      width:50px; */
    }


    /*
    This following statements selects each category individually that contains an input element that is a checkbox and is checked (or selected) and changes the background color of the span element.

    .first input:checked + span{background-color: #303030;}
    .second input:checked + span{background-color: #424242;}
    .third input:checked + span{background-color: #424242;}
    .fourth input:checked + span{background-color: #424242;}
```

I tried to do hover with this code, which will change color of only transparent part of image. It works although I am not sure that I am getting always right color.

```
.cat.first label {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.cat.first::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: inherit;
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
  z-index: -1;
}

.cat.first:hover::before {
  background-color: #424242;
}
```

But I am not sure how to do this change of color of transparent part when button is checked.
Any suggestions?

Comment: You'll need to apply the background color at least on the same "level" on the z axis as the background image, otherwise the background color will cover the whole image. So if you apply the background image to `.cat` here, then you will have to apply the background color on that as well, and not anything _inside_ of it. Which would mean you'd have to use `:has()` - which currently has not support in FIrefox, unless the user explicitly enables it.

Comment: If you apply the background image to the `span` that follows the input instead, then you can still use the adjacent sibling combinator, `input:checked + span { ... }`

Comment: How does the input element have any effect given it seems to remain at display: none? Am I missing something?